# Return null for non-nullable columns when no records found

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Entity types

```
public class Person
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Guid TeamId { get; set; } // mandatory foreign key

    public virtual Team Team { get; set; } // navigation property

    // dozen other properties
}

public class Team
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method which returns team id for a given person id. Method's return type defined as `Guid?`. Nullable because there are possibility that given person id does not exist in database.

```
public Task<Guid?> GetTeamIdFor(Guid personId)
{
    using (var context = _createDbContext())
    {
        return await context.Persons
            .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
            .Select(p => p.TeamId)
            .FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Issue is that `FirstOrDefault()` return default value of `Guid` type (type of `TeamId` column). So instead of returning `null` method return empty Guid `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.

I can achieve desired result by loading whole entity, but I try to avoid loading extra, not required data.

```
var person = await context.FindAsync(personId);
return person?.TeamId;
```

I can do check for empty Guid before returning value

```
var teamId = await context.Where(p => p.Id = personId).Select(p => p.TeamId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
return teamId == Guid.Empy ? default(Guid?) : teamId;
```

Question: Is there a way to make query return nullable Guid without loading whole entity or without operations after result materialization?

Comment: I've not tested this, but would casting TeamId to (Guid?), followed by .FirstOrDefault() work?

Comment: @JamieBurns that's what I would've tried (`.Select(p => (Guid?)p.TeamId).FirstOrDefault();`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can cast TeamId to a nullable Guid, which allows FirstOrDefault to return null if nothing is found:

```
Guid? id = context.Persons
  .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
  .Select(p => (Guid?)p.TeamId)
  .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue recently and this is how I got around it.

```
 /// <summary>
 /// Gets or sets Telephone 2 Type.
 /// </summary>
 public int? TelephoneTwoTypeId { get; set; }

 /// <summary>
 /// Gets or sets Telephone 2 Type data structure.
 /// </summary>
 public TelephoneTypes? TelephoneTwoType { get; set; }
```

When doing the migration it should look something like this too

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
 {
     migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
         name: "TelephoneTwoTypeId",
         schema: "dbo",
         table: "tableName",
         nullable: true,
         oldClrType: typeof(int),
         oldType: "int");
 }

 protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
 {
     migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
         name: "TelephoneTwoTypeId",
         schema: "dbo",
         table: "tableName",
         type: "int",
         nullable: false,
         oldClrType: typeof(int),
         oldNullable: true);
 }
```

so, if you you make the items nullable this should work for you. Please also excuse the int as an Id in code first. I wasnt the original table designer

Comment: Thanks, but I can not change type to nullable because `TeamId` is mandatory for `Person` entity

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=Remarks-,The%20default%20value%20for%20reference%20and%20nullable%20types%20is%20null,described%20in%20the%20Example%20section.):

> Sometimes the value of default(TSource) is not the default value that you want to use if the collection contains no elements. Instead of checking the result for the unwanted default value and then changing it if necessary, you can use the `DefaultIfEmpty<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource>, TSource)`

So in your case:

```
public Task<Guid?> GetTeamIdFor(Guid personId)
{
   Guid? defaultGuid = null;
   using (var context = _createDbContext())
   {
    return await context.Persons
        .DefaultIfEmpty(defaultGuid)
        .Where(p => p.Id == personId)
        .Select(p => p.TeamId)
        .FirstOrDefault();
   }
}
```

Comment: I believe this requires `p.TeamId` to be of type `Guid?` instead of `Guid`. The compiler won't implicitly convert the type. Should be fixed if you cast `p.TeamId` to `Guid?`.

Comment: Grazie, link is for `Enumerable`, but `Queryable` docs has similar statement :)

Comment: Sorry, `.DefaultIfNotEmpty(null)` will not compile. `.DefaultIfEmpty` is useful when we need to return different than default value, but still value of same type. In my case different type should be returned.

Comment: Sorry, this will not compile, because `DefaultIfEmpty` expects a value of the type returned by previous `Select`, which is `Guid`.

Comment: Ok, and what if you put DefaultIfEmpty before Select? I update my answer.